# How do I show HTML in an WPF application?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WPF and need some help and guidance.

I am building a client app in VS2010 that will store HTML in a database, and I need to display this html with images in my application when the user clicks a "preview html" button.

so my question is,

How do I display my stored HTML as a web page in a wpf page? Does anyone know of a sample application that does this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem.  Here is my solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533767/reference-an-image-imbedded-in-a-wpf-application-from-within-an-html-file-used-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the html in web browser control.

Comment: I don't see a web browser control in the toolbox in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

When the HTML is saved, render it and save a preview image.  Then just pull the preview image and display that.

If you can't, you can always just pull the HTML and run it through your full render sequence, whatever that is.

Comment: How do you render and save a preview image?